# Boruvka Algorithm for minimal spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

i was thinking about the implementation in C/C++ of Boruvka MST Algorithm. this algorithm creates N set of vertices and for each of them chooses the edge with minimal cost. I was thinking to code in this way: I have a structure for each vertex with: vertex tag and all its edges. So I proceed with analyze the first vertex and I choose its minimal edge: then I add to the result the vertex and the destination vertex. and so I proceed with others iteration for all the vertex. But in this way I have to make a sort for all the edges for each vertex, that seem to be computation prohibitive!

please let me know if my reasoning are right, and help me to find out a solution,
thank you!

Comment: What you describe is not a Boruvka step, but actually Tarjan's ultraviolet rule. A Boruvka step would chose a minimal edge for all remaining vertices at the same time and only then do an update for all of these. Then, for the update you don't have to sort the new fused lists, again, you just have to merge them. This can be done in  overall linear time per Boruvka step.